# Source and Sink in DAGs

Tags: graph, proof, directed-acyclic-graphs

Consider a graph G which is a DAG. Prove that in the graph G', which is obtained by reversing all the edges of G, the source(s)/sink(s) in G would become sink(s)/source(s) respectively.

I can see it clearly but I'm quite unable to give a formal proof for it. Help me out. :')

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) vertex with indegree 0 is called source and vertex with outdegree 0 is called sink.

Reversing edges, indegree and outdegree are interchanged for each vertex. That means if vertex v in G have indegree d1 and outdegree d2, than v in G' has indegree d2 and outdegree d1.

Vertex v is source in G <=> v has indegree 0 in G <=> v has outdegree 0 in G' <=> v is sink in G'.